# AES in ECB mode with OpenSSL library not producing expected results

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I have been trying to become more familiar with the OpenSSL library and to do so I wanted to make some programs that encrypted text using different modes of operation. I have created a program that I want to encrypt and decrypt using the ECB mode, but the results are not what I was expecting.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>


//static const unsigned char key[]={01234567890123456789012345678900};


int main()
{


    int keylength;
    printf("Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256!]:\n");
    scanf("%d", &keylength);

    /* generate a key with a given length */
    unsigned char aes_key[keylength];
    memset(aes_key, 0, sizeof(aes_key));
    if (!RAND_bytes(aes_key, keylength))
     {
        exit(-1);
     }
    aes_key[keylength-1] = '\0';

    unsigned char text[] = "TestText TestText"; //Assign text to be encrypted
    unsigned char enc_out[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]; //Set to 16 bytes
    unsigned char dec_out[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key; //establish AES enc and dec key

    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, 128, &enc_key); 
    AES_encrypt(text, enc_out, &enc_key);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, 128, &dec_key);
    AES_decrypt(enc_out, dec_out, &dec_key);

    int x;

    printf("original:\t");
    for(x=0;*(text+x)!=0x00;x++)          
    printf("%X ",*(text+x));
    printf("\nencrypted:\t");
    for(x=0;*(enc_out+x)!=0x00;x++)
    printf("%X ",*(enc_out+x));
    printf("\ndecrypted:\t");
    for(x=0;*(dec_out+x)!=0x00;x++)
    printf("%X ",*(dec_out+x));
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I know that for the ECB mode identical plaintext blocks should be encrypted into identical ciphertext blocks, but when I run my code this doesn't happen. Here is an example:

```
original: 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74 2E 20 20 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74 2E
encrypted: A2 FE 93 40 F5 92 95 F A2 5A D0 4A A6 53 95 58 54 65 73 74
           54 65 78 74 2E 20 20 54 65 73 74 54 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74
           2E 20 20 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74 2E
decrypted: 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74 2E 20 20 54 65 73 74 54 54 65 73 74
           54 65 78 74 2E 20 20 54 65 73 74 54 65 78 74 2E
```

First, I have the input text turned into Hex, then it should be encrypted using the ECB Mode, and lastly everything should be decrypted. The two strings of text I encrypted are identical, but the hex formatted text doesn't show this. The identical plaintext do not share the same ciphertext. The hex of the plaintext also seems to be tailing the encrypted text and I am not sure why that is occurring. Can anyone shed some light as to why the encryption is not working as it should? Are there any mistakes in my code that are not providing the necessary results? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The encrypt/decrypt functions deal with binary data and not C-strings. You cannot simply look for a `nul-byte`, e.g `for(x=0;*(dec_out+x)!=0x00;x++)` will not work.

Comment: Thank you.  I was mistaken in thinking the functions would work after the first block.  Should I change the code to encrypt using input lengths instead of inputting text?  Thanks

Comment: Add `string.h` (or use a simple loop) to get the length of `text` (e.g. `size_t textlen = strlen (text) ;` Then you know the original and expected decrypted length. (don't forget `strlen` does not include the `nul-terminating` char)

Comment: I will try that; thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong here.

First: You are mixing up sizes in bits and bytes. A 128-bit key is 16 bytes long, not 128 bytes. This is mostly harmless, as you just end up generating too large of a key.

Second: You are assuming that inputs and outputs from AES, including keys, are null-terminated. They are not. Everything past the first 16 bytes of output you're printing is random garbage, and the key does not (and should not be!) null-terminated.

Third: Your test input (`"TestText TestText"`) is too long to fit into a single AES block. `AES_encrypt()` only operates on a single block.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and explains why encryption isn't happening after the first block.

Comment: Also, if you then:  keylength = keylength / 8; // length in *bytes*, then you do *not* want to aes_key[keylength-1] = '\0'; // <-- Don't truncate the key!!! (By "truncate" I mean, set the last 8 bits to a known, constant value.)

Comment: @JimFlood Thanks for emphasizing that. Clarified in my answer.